# How to build Gnuplot with MSVC ? (syscfg.h(377): error)

Tags: c++, makefile, gnuplot

I'm trying to build gnuplot with Visual Studio 2015. To this end I run the Makefile located in the `config\msvc` :

1. Start the Microsoft Visual C++ command shell
2. change to the `config\msvc`
3. Run `nmake -f Makefile`

but I obtain the following fatal error :

```
c:\.......\gnuplot\src\gnuplot-5.0.1\gnuplot-5.0.1\src\syscfg.h(377): error C2632: 'char' ne peut pas être suivi de 'bool'
```

Is it the correct way to build the  5.0.1 version of gnuplot for windows ? Have you already seen this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `bool` type: *Microsoft Visual Studio* (since version 2013) package includes a library with `bool` as a type. Somewhy, `HAVE_STDBOOL_H` is not defined on your system. [The issue has already been faced when compiling other software.](https://github.com/chansen/p5-time-moment/issues/12)

I can suggest you two possibilities:

1) write `#define HAVE_STDBOOL_H` in `gnuplot-5.0.1\src\syscfg.h` just above line 370

2) Open `Makefile`, add `/DHAVE_STDBOOL_H` to `CFLAGS`, or, even to `CBASEFLAGS`.

gnuplot-5.0.1\src\syscfg.h (370-384):

```
#if HAVE_STDBOOL_H
# include <stdbool.h>
#else
# if ! HAVE__BOOL
#  ifdef __cplusplus
typedef bool _Bool;
#  else
typedef unsigned char _Bool;
#  endif
# endif
# define bool _Bool
# define false 0
# define true 1
# define __bool_true_false_are_defined 1
#endif
```

The way you build it is believed to be correct, it agrees with the original guide provided in `Makefile`:

> Start the Microsoft Visual C++ command shell (e.g. via link installed
>   setup)
>   
>  Change to the gnuplot\config\msvc directory
>   
>  Edit the Makefile to match your setup. (If you don't have the optional libraries, you will probably have to disable some parts.)
>   
> Now run:
>   
>   nmake

Comment: Thank you it works: I have defined `#define HAVE_STDBOOL_H  1` in the config.h file of the /msvc folder. So for other people who may face a similar problem, have a look to this config.h file.